# Continous scrolling from scrollview to nested colelctionView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have collectionView nested inside a scrollView. Both of which scroll Vertically.

In my main scroll View I want to stop it's scrolling when reaching scrollView.contentOffset.y > someValue, and enable scrolling in collectionView

But I want this to happen in one continuous motion without needing to lift finger in between.

Full view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want continues scrolling, you should not stop the scrolling of your main scroll view. And you should set the main `scrollView.contentOffset.y` as constant value once it's reached your max offset(`scrollView.contentOffset.y > someValue`). And you can increase/decrease the `contentOffset.y` of your collectionView as per you main scrollview motion.

Example:

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 50) {
 scrollView.contentOffset.y = 50.0;
 collectionView.contentOffset.y += 1; //you can do your scroll up/down calculation over here
}
```

Comment: Ohh, found out my mistake there. That helps a lot! Almost made it work.
One thing more, if you can help, my view looks like the pic in the question, and contentView calls a collectionView, so what would be the way to do manage calculation of collectionView offset

Comment: `offSet = scrollingView.contentOffset.y` <br/> `var storedOffSet = ["offSet" : offSet]` <br/> `scrollingView.contentOffset.y = 35` <br/> `var nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()` <br/> `nc.postNotificationName("Minimize View", object: self, userInfo: storedOffSet)` <br/> But since I am setting offset to 35, it is causing problems

Comment: meaning is it possible to set a contentoffset but still get a value  of how much user has scrolled